# Unable to add new property to object extracted from props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am passing props to another component but In my receiving component I want to initialize a state with props but I want to add an additional property to that props(containing object type data) and then initialize the state,
My state-initialized login is in useEffect, where I want to add a new property to an object

**But the problem is**

- When I add a property to an object(props) it didn't add,
- When I add a property inside a `console.log` mentioned in `useEffect` below it shows
  the correct results

  ```
   import EditParts from "./EditPartsChange";

   function MechanicTable() {
   const [partsList,setpartsList]= useState([{id:123,name:"oil filter"},{id:124,name:"air filter"}]);
   return(
     <>
       <EditParts partsList={partsList} />
     </>
   );  
   }
   export default MechanicTable;
  ```

_

```
    function EditParts({ partsList }) {
      const [_partsList, setPartsList] = useState([]);
      useEffect(() => {
        let parts = [...partsList];
        parts = parts.map((part) => ({
           ...part,
           dbvalue: "db value",
        }));
    // If I console the parts variable after completing the loop then it also don't show me the updated results

    //Show only correct result 
     console.log(
       parts.map((part) => ({
        ...part,
        dbvalue: "db value",
      }))
     );
    //Show only correct result ☝️

        const unSubscribe = setPartsList(parts);

        return () => {unSubscribe;};
      }, [partsList]);

    return(<></>);
    }
    export default EditParts;
```

This is the link to the code
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-crud-firebase-forked-ypp9qi?file=/src/App.js

```
<EditPartsChange partsList={part.partsList} />
```

is the Effected area in the code

Comment: what are trying to achieve here ? as you are just mapping over the props that is a shallow copy of props

Comment: I want to add a property to every array element and then initialize it to my state, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: why not do it while passing from parent component itself ?

Comment: I just copy pasted your code and I can see the value with key `dbvalue` even once I console log after the loop.

Comment: Actually it is a part of requirement to add new property in the child component

Comment: yep with your code it should work, may you can add more info on what is not working, a reproducible sample for e.g.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? You never access `_partsList`. See here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-crud-firebase-forked-gg3b9r

Answer (score 0):

Issue is not reproducible, however this piece of code itself is sufficient.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
        const parts = partsList.map((part) => ({
           ...part,
           dbvalue: "db value",
        }));
   

        const unSubscribe = setPartsList([...parts]);

        return () => {unSubscribe;};
      }, [partsList]);
```

Comment: no still not working, same result but without `dbValue`

Comment: Have you tried running your project in other react online editor? If so in codeSandbox, could you please share the sandbox link.

Comment: working on it..

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-crud-firebase-forked-ypp9qi?file=/src/EditParts.js

` <EditPartsChange partsList={part.partsList} />` is the child where problem is occuring @codinn.dev

Comment: I can see the `dbValue` key in it when you are logging it.

Comment: I don't know what and where am i missing but the same code is not working for me but it is working fine in codesandbox

Comment: Have you tried rendering the `_partsList` array in the UI using `map`?